# Vim Latex Suite can't find latex command using Pathogen

Tags: vim, path, latex, pathogen, latex-suite

## Background

I was having dual boot issues with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10, which eventually resulted in a boot loop and since I need Ubuntu 16.04.3 for an Operating Systems class I decided to load up an ISO into one of my USBs with Rufus, reformat my Windows partitions from GPT to NTFS to get around some nasty bootmg/efi issues and here we are, good as new, except for one thing...

## Problem

The only thing I haven't been able to successfully reinstall has been Latex Suite for Vim. Installation last time had been an easy extraction into .vim, but after some deliberation I elected to use Pathogen.
I've installed Pathogen using

`mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim`

Which works for color schemes, etc., and every other aspect of latex-suite save for compiling, generating this every time I try to compile (using \ll):

```
/bin/bash: latex: command not found
```

I installed texlive which does then allow me to compile using vim, but I'd prefer not to use this solution if I don't have to (in fact I've already removed it, its more of a plan b for now given it's obstructive and non-intuitive compilation errors). I looked at the other questions asking how to install Latex Suite through pathogen and didn't see anything else similar to what I'm working on; below is self-explanatory in regards to installation structure.

```
~/.vim/bundle$ ls
vim-archery  vim-latex-1.10.0
```

Obvious running pdflatex and latex can't be found because they are not in my $PATH but I was under the impression that with a good, recommended package manager like Pathogen I wouldn't need to which is what originally raised the red flag for me as its whole job is to modify the runtime path. I thought maybe trying `sudo vim text.tex` might work in case there hadn't been adequate permissions for Pathogen to modify runtime path but no dice.

### .vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

colorscheme archery

let g:tex_flavor='latex'

set sw=2
```

Comment: your error is from bash not from vim, your vim plugin works fine but there is no `latex` command on your system. Try enter `latex` in a terminal, once that runs, your vim plugin will run

Comment: I was also trying to wrap my head around the same issue but I think it boils down to what @DoktorOSwaldo said: the `latex` binary is not part of the installation of `vim-latex`, and you need to provide it separately. I couldn't find any mention of this anywhere on the vim-latex github page nor their sourceforge page, though, but looked at the files within `vim-latex-1.10.0` to find out.